# Reading in JSON file received error message

Tags: python, json

I'm new with python and I ran the code below and got this error message. I saw from another similar post that I have two json files? But I don't really understand since I only load one into my jupyter notebook. I tried deleting the json file and reupload it to jupyter notebook but it doesn't work.

How would I be able to fix this? Thank you.

```
import json

with open('file.json') as f:
    json = json.load(f)
    
print(json)
```

I received this message:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-5b475df8ffe8> in <module>
      2 
      3 with open('file.json') as f:
----> 4     json = json.load(f)
      5 
      6 print(json)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py in load(fp, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    291     kwarg; otherwise ``JSONDecoder`` is used.
    292     """
--> 293     return loads(fp.read(),
    294         cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
    295         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    344             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    345             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 346         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    347     if cls is None:
    348         cls = JSONDecoder

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):
--> 340             raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
    341         return obj
    342 

JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 2702)
```

Comment: dont use the variable name 'json', it's the module name you import

Comment: maybe u should read file content first: `my_var = json.loads(f.read())`

Answer (score 1):

About the error, you should first check whether it is an error in your json file. Consider showing your json file data out here. And according to the error has thrown out, Line 2 has some mistakes

Comment: I had a similar error, and it turned out my JSON had an error in the syntax, which was causing it to fail.  If you see this error, I would double-check the JSON since your code is written correctly.